# on Click of text View inside a List Item not getting proper value

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a ListView ,In that each ListItem having some items(textViews),In which one textView is having click event.That I have put in my custom adater,And I am calling an asynctask on its cLick event,For that I want a value when I click on that textView its "queID" I want,But currently I am gettong it null..Please see my code and help me please..!
"qoute" is that textView.On which I have put click event.how to set"buyer_req_Id" and get tag on it?I currrently successfully get the tag on each "ListItem" Click event ,I want to set the same tag on ListItem's textView.Inside java class I have put only adapter,In which I want "buyer_request_id".
**Adapter.java**

```
package com.epe.yehki.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epe.yehki.ui.BuyingreqActivity;
import com.epe.yehki.ui.BuyingreqActivity.GetQuoteList;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.example.yehki.R;

public class BuyingRequestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> BuyingRequestArray;
    private Context mContext;

    public BuyingRequestAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.BuyingRequestArray = productList;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.BuyingRequestArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder;
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_buying_req, paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();
            localViewholder.sub = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.sub));
            localViewholder.expDate = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.exp_date));
            localViewholder.quote = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.quote));
            localViewholder.status = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.status));
            localViewholder.lastUpdate = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.last_updated));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);

        } else {

            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
        }

        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::values:::::::::::::::" + BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME));
        localViewholder.sub.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME));
        localViewholder.expDate.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE));
        localViewholder.lastUpdate.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_DATE_MODIFIED));
        localViewholder.quote.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT));
        localViewholder.quote.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
        localViewholder.status.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_STATUS));

        localViewholder.quote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::quote clicked...!!");

                GetQuoteList getQuoteList = ((BuyingreqActivity) mContext).new GetQuoteList();
                getQuoteList.execute();

            }
        });
        return paramView;

    }

    static class Viewholder {
        TextView sub;
        TextView lastUpdate;
        TextView expDate;
        TextView quote;
        TextView status;

    }

}
```

**java class(asynctask)**

```
public class GetQuoteList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BuyingreqActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            scr_post.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scr_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            quote_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            // String query = "?customer_id=" +
            // Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "")
            // + "&buyer_request_id=23";
            String query = "?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "") + "&buyer_request_id=" + buyer_request_id;
            query = query.replace(" ", "%20");
            viewURL = Const.API_QUOTE_RECIEVED + query;
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::ADDRESS URL:::::::::::::::::" + viewURL);
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(viewURL, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST)) {
                        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::true::::::::::::::::" + jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_LIST));
                        requestes = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST);

                        if (requestes != null && requestes.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts

                            System.out.println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::" + flag);
                            for (int i = 0; i < requestes.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = requestes.getJSONObject(i);

                                buyerID = c.getString(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);
                                System.out.println(":::::::::::::::MY buying request:::::::::::::" + buyerID);
                                String product_name = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                                String quote_id = c.getString(Const.TAG_QUOTE_ID);
                                String supplier_name = c.getString(Const.TAG_SUPPLIER_NAME);
                                String status = c.getString(Const.TAG_STATUS);

                                HashMap<String, String> quote = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                quote.put(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID, buyerID);
                                quote.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, product_name);
                                quote.put(Const.TAG_QUOTE_ID, quote_id);
                                quote.put(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE, supplier_name);
                                quote.put(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT, status);
                                queList.add(quote);
                                System.out.println(":::::::::::::Buyer request ID:" + buyerID);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * 
             * */

            quoteAdapter = new QuoteAdapter(BuyingreqActivity.this, queList);

            quoteList.setAdapter(quoteAdapter);

        }

    }
```

Comment: where exactly are you getting null, what value you want on click of text view to async task ?

Comment: Exactly "NullPointer" is not my problem ,My question is how to set the same tag to the textView of "ListItem" inside Custom adapter.?Like I have setTag to whole ListItem as"paramView.setTag(localViewholder);",SO for the TextView "quote" how can I set the same tag.to get value.On its Click event.Which I have Implemented inside Adapter class.

Comment: you can set tag to any view. use setTag() on text view in your getView method

Comment: @Neji-I know but I have searched a lot,and having no idea how to do it.Can you give me some small example code..

Answer (score 0):

// Try this way,hope this will help you...

localViewholder.quote.setTag(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID));
localViewholder.quote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::quote clicked...!!");
      String buyerId = v.getTag().toString(); // user this buyerId for your requirement 
      System.out.println("Buyer Id Is "+buyerId);
      GetQuoteList getQuoteList = ((BuyingreqActivity) mContext).new GetQuoteList();
      getQuoteList.execute();

   }
});
```

Comment: harsh-Tahnk you haresh but its giving me en error with red Line that "getTag cant be resolved or not a field"..!!! :(

Comment: Sorry i forgot "()" bracket after "getTag" so now you check i have edited my ans.

Comment: I got nullPointer on "String buyerId = v.getTag().toString();"

Comment: can you please let me know how to get buyer id from your BuyingRequestArray or which Const tag you used for buyer id ?

Comment: actually I want is when I click ListItem I am getting a value "buyer_req_ID" inside ListItem's click event as "String buyReqID = reqList.get(position).get(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);and I want to get the same value onClick of textView too..

Comment: have you also set ListView setonItemClickListener() ?

Comment: Yes haresh..There are to diffrent things I have to do So that

Comment: which is not possible becz when you set ListView setOnItemClickListener it take whole view of ListView Item and you also declare onClickListener for ListView item child so here child click listener never take becz it parent have already click Listener have you understood what i mean to say ?

Comment: So...How can it possible when ,A ListView having "buttons" and they also having Click events and "ListItems " too...!!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52568/discussion-between-haresh-and-jigar-jims)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem as below by changing my asynctask to void to string :
**adapter.java**

```
package com.epe.yehki.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epe.yehki.ui.BuyingreqActivity;
import com.epe.yehki.ui.BuyingreqActivity.GetQuoteList;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.example.yehki.R;

public class BuyingRequestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> BuyingRequestArray;
    private Context mContext;

    public BuyingRequestAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> reqList) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.BuyingRequestArray = reqList;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.BuyingRequestArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder;
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_buying_req, paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();

            localViewholder.sub = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.sub));
            localViewholder.expDate = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.exp_date));
            localViewholder.quote = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.quote));
            localViewholder.status = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.status));
            localViewholder.lastUpdate = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.last_updated));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);
            /* localViewholder.quote.setTag(localViewholder); */

        } else {

            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
            /* localViewholder.quote = ((TextView) paramView.getTag()); */
        }
        final String reqId = BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::My reqId:::::::::::" + reqId);
        localViewholder.sub.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME));
        localViewholder.expDate.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE));
        localViewholder.lastUpdate.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_DATE_MODIFIED));
        localViewholder.quote.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT));
        localViewholder.quote.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
        localViewholder.status.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_STATUS));

        localViewholder.quote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::quote clicked...!!");

                System.out.println("Buyer Id Is " + reqId);
                GetQuoteList getQuoteList = ((BuyingreqActivity) mContext).new GetQuoteList();
                getQuoteList.execute(reqId);

            }
        });
        return paramView;

    }

    static class Viewholder {
        TextView sub;
        TextView lastUpdate;
        TextView expDate;
        TextView quote;
        TextView status;

    }

}
```